# Recommended number of miners in a private ethereum network

Tags: go-ethereum, mining

Imagine an ethereum private network with a single node that has 30 peers, 10 of them miners. I have many doubts.

- How is the recommended number of miners 33% percent of the total amount of peers in a node?
- Get more o fewer miners in what affects? (In a private network that the idea is not to get ether rewards)
- I understand that having fewer miners affects the speed of validating transactions and generating the block, doesn't it?

Thanks !!!

Comment: In a private network, you need to must use another consensus than PoW, maybe PoA or maybe  some version of BFT. And what do you mean by "a single node that has 30 peers"! peers are also nodes, aren't they?

Comment: So using PoA with just one single miner is valid to mint the blocks of transaction without affect the time to generate them. Maybe I was wrong, but I was thinking that a node could be a group of peer's and a peer can or cannot be a miner peer.

Comment: I’m sure “peer” is another word for “node”. Anyway a privat Eth network with only 1 node does not make sense. Usually multiple Parties agree to run a private network with PoA or BFT and each one of those parties run a node and only those nodes can “validate” and submit blocks to the network (no mining), later new parties could join the network or leave it and other external parties could run their own nodes and connect to the network but they can only check the transaction but cannot produce blocks. Sry I don’t have useful information about performance and spam attack of such a private network